# script to parse integer and convert it to char code

Tags: shell-script, string, character-encoding

I need to parse string containing hash code value and convert the hash code is equivalent char representation. Here is the example code of it.

```
I see that you#39;re eligible to get ticket for show on your device#44;
```

now, the script should output to

```
I see that you're eligible to get ticket for show on your device,
```

Comment: Is this html encoding?

Comment: yes, it uses the html entity encoding style but without the &.

Comment: There are tools that can do html decoding, so use sed to convert it to “proper” html encoding, then put it through one of these decoders.

Comment: How do you get from 146 to `\`` (grave accent, U+0060)? Or do you mean `’` (right single quotation mark), which is at 146 in the ibm-cp1252 character set for instance?

Comment: After your edit, that still doesn't add up. HTML `&#146;` is a control character, `&#96;` is `\`` (backtick, grave accent), `'` (apostrophe) is `&#39;`, `’` (right single quotation mark) is `&#8217;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perl is good for this:

```
$ str='I see that you#146;re eligible to get ticket for show on your device#44;'
$ perl -pe 's/#(\d+);/chr($1)/ge' <<<"$str"
I see that you’re eligible to get ticket for show on your device,
```

I had to set my terminal's encoding to WINDOWS-1252 to get that output. Decimal 146 is not a valid [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)
character.

---

To treat those codes as HTML entities, we'll add the missing ampersand, and decode:

```
perl -MHTML::Entities -lne 's/(#\d+;)/&$1/g; print decode_entities($_)' <<<"$str"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can't use anything other than simple shell script :(

Comment: you need to output character with code point 146, not byte 146. (This will be a 2 byte code in utf-8)

Comment: Yes I agree, this uses UTF encoding. Sorry If I've missed to mention that.

Comment: There's a great number of charset that have `RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` on 146, not only windows-1252 (all the other windows-125x as well for instance). Of course, using that character here is wrong, the OP should use the apostrophe `'` instead.

Comment: agree, corrected the question.

Answer (score 0):

In bash you could do:

```
$ str='I see that you#39;re eligible to get ticket for show on your device#44;'
$ re='#([0-9]*);'; while [[ $str =~ $re ]]; do b="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; c=$(printf "$(printf '\\U%x' "$b")"); str=${str//#$b;/$c}; done; echo "$a"
I see that you're eligible to get ticket for show on your device,
```